# How to add dots between section and page Toc

Tags: table-of-contents, tocloft

There are a lot of topics for that. But those don't help me with my toc.
Even that command `\renewcommand{\cftsecleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}}`. Do you have any guesses why?

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 14pt]{article}
\usepackage[14pt]{extsizes}


\usepackage{floatrow,caption}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,pdftex]{xcolor}
\floatsetup[table]{capposition=top}
\captionsetup[table]{singlelinecheck=false, justification=RaggedLeft}
\usepackage{extsizes}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{EuScript}
\usepackage{wrapfig}

\usepackage[left=30mm, top=20mm, right=15mm, bottom=20mm ]{geometry}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[tocflat]{tocstyle}
\usetocstyle{standard}

\usepackage{tocloft}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\tableofcontents{%
  \null\hfill\textbf{\Large\contentsname}\hfill\null\par
  \@mkboth{\MakeUppercase\contentsname}{\MakeUppercase\contentsname}%
  \@starttoc{toc}%

}

\renewcommand{\cftsecleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\section{one}
\subsection{one one}

\section{two}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please remove irrelative packages to make your example more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be very careful when you use two packages having similar utilities. That often leads to compatibility issues. Here in your example, keep `tocloft` and leave out `tocstyle` solves the problem.

```
\documentclass{article}

%\usepackage[tocflat]{tocstyle}
%\usetocstyle{standard}

\usepackage{tocloft}
% redefining \tableofcontents is irrelavent
%\makeatletter
%\renewcommand\tableofcontents{%
%  \null\hfill\textbf{\Large\contentsname}\hfill\null\par
%  \@mkboth{\MakeUppercase\contentsname}{\MakeUppercase\contentsname}%
%  \@starttoc{toc}%
%}
%\makeatother

\renewcommand{\cftsecleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\section{one}
\subsection{one one}

\section{two}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You were forcing a standard tocstyle which has now been removed

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 14pt]{article}
\usepackage[14pt]{extsizes}


\usepackage{floatrow,caption}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,pdftex]{xcolor}
\floatsetup[table]{capposition=top}
%\captionsetup[table]{singlelinecheck=false, justification=RaggedLeft}
\usepackage{extsizes}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{EuScript}
\usepackage{wrapfig}

\usepackage[left=30mm, top=20mm, right=15mm, bottom=20mm ]{geometry}
\usepackage{setspace}
%\usepackage[tocflat]{tocstyle}%<----------removed
%\usetocstyle{standard}%<-------------------removed

\usepackage{tocloft}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\tableofcontents{%
    \null\hfill\textbf{\Large\contentsname}\hfill\null\par
    \@mkboth{\MakeUppercase\contentsname}{\MakeUppercase\contentsname}%
    \@starttoc{toc}%    
}
\renewcommand{\cftsecleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}}
\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents
    
    \section{one}
    \subsection{one one}
    
    \section{two}
\end{document}
```