# How do I add dots for sections in the table of contents. I used one method but it only worked for section I wrote after toc and not before toc

Tags: table-of-contents

I want to create a TOC like this in my document:

[image: i want to create toc like this in my latex]

However, in my document it does not show on abstract but shows on the other sections. I used this command to add dots:

```
\titlecontents{section}[0pt]{\addvspace{0.8em}}{\bfseries\contentslabel[\thecontentslabel]{01em}}{\bfseries}{\hspace{0em}\titlerule*[0.3pc]{.}\contentspage}
```

I also used:

```
\renewcommand{\cftsecleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}}
```

and it also didn't work. This is my code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{tocloft}      
\usepackage{mathptmx}      
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{amsmath}
%\numberwithin{figure}{chapter}
\usepackage{titletoc}

\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{roman}  
 
\section{abstract}
hello
\newpage
{
\titlecontents{section}[0pt]{\addvspace{0.8em}}{\bfseries\contentslabel[\thecontentslabel]{01em}}{\bfseries}{\hspace{0em}\titlerule*[0.3pc]{.}\contentspage}
\tableofcontents
}
\newpage
\section{list of abbreviation}
aa= apple

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please show a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/277964) of what you've tried. The example should start with `\documentclass`, followed by all *needed* packages an preamble definitions, and should also contain an abstract, the table of contents and ideally at least one section, and end with `\end{document}`. Currently it is not clear, why is should not work for sections before the table of contents, but only for sections after the table of contents.

Comment: Tested: If I add a `\section{Test}` before the `\tableofcontents` in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/550752/277964) to the [related question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/550743/277964) the corresponding entry in the table of contents *has* the dots.

Comment: `\@startoc` formats all sections at the same time using `\l@section`.  I try to avoid titletoc as unneded and confusing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMHO your `\titlecontents` command makes more harm than benefit. Using `tocloft` to configure *all* ToC entries using:

```
\renewcommand{\cftsecleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}}
```

from [the old answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/550752/277964) works without your extra code.

But it seems you also want very low dot distance for all entry levels. For this you can additionally change `\cftdotsep`:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
%\usepackage{graphicx}% not needed for the example
\usepackage{tocloft}      
%\usepackage{mathptmx}% not needed for the example
%\usepackage{float}% not needed for the example
%\usepackage{amsmath}% not needed for the example
%\numberwithin{figure}{chapter}
%\usepackage{titletoc}% not needed for the example
\renewcommand{\cftsecleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}}
\renewcommand{\cftdotsep}{.5}% use the same dot distance for all levels

\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{roman}
 
\section{abstract}
hello
\newpage
\tableofcontents
\newpage
\section{list of abbreviation}
aa= apple

\end{document}
```

[image: dots for section entries]

If you additionally want the vertical distance before section entries and the fonts of section entries to be used also for subsection entries, you can use also change `\cftbeforesubsecskip`, `\cftsubsecfont`, and `\cftsubsecpagefont`:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tocloft}      
\renewcommand{\cftsecleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}}
\renewcommand{\cftdotsep}{.5}% use the same dot distance for all levels
\setlength{\cftbeforesubsecskip}{\cftbeforesecskip}
\renewcommand{\cftsubsecfont}{\cftsecfont}
\renewcommand{\cftsubsecpagefont}{\cftsecpagefont}

\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{roman}
 
\section{abstract}
hello
\newpage
\tableofcontents
\newpage
\section{list of abbreviation}
aa= apple
\subsection{a subsection}
test
\subsection{another subsection}
test

\end{document}
```

[image: with distances and bold]

Please see the `tocloft` manual for more information.